# Change the order of libraries using IDE

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a few external libraries that I am linking into my project.  They are being statically linked and have order dependencies.  I have tried to change the order by moving the library up or down in the Paths and Symbols dialogue, but it does not seem to have an effect on the Makefile that is generated.

Answer (score 1):

The REDHAWK IDE currently does not respect the order of libraries in the Paths and Symbols dialogue as of version 1.8.4. A bug has been logged to reflect this.

As a work-around in the mean time, you can comment-out the inclusion of the Makefile.am.ide in your Makefile.am. Then you can provide a manual list of the libraries in the correct order in the Makefile.am.